# win7 64bit - manually change driver signature

Tags: windows, driver, signature

I want to edit/change driver signature. Because when i start it, I got message, that signature isn't set. The only option now is to click F8 and then "Disable driver signature enforcement". But I don't really want to use this option, it's insecure. So how I can set signature for that driver? Or maybe disable driver signature enforcement for ONLY selected driver? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You must purchase a certificate.  In addition, 64-bit drivers must be submitted for quality testing.  After you passed that test you get the additional certificate that's required to bypass the driver signature check.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh833792

Comment: @HansPassant No, you don't need to submit anything for quality testing. A proper code signature is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you purchase a code signing certificate from Verisign or Globalsign (other CAs won't work), you can remove existing signature if it's present for the driver and then apply your own signature by signing the driver file. Signing is done using signtool.exe from Windows SDK or from Windows Driver Kit. When the driver is signed, you need to include a [cross-signing certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487315.aspx).